# Using SUBSTRING and ROUND on WHERE clausule in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Having the following table

```
name | latitude | longitude
---------------------------
  A  |  20.123  |  114.8965
  B  |  1.987   |  -0.39123
```

For a given input (`myinput`), for example `20.1` I would like to know if it already exist on the table.

This means that I need to take the `latitude` (or `longitude`, but let's focus only on `latitude` in order to simplify the question) of each row of the table, get the first decimal and round it to the upper value and compare to the `input`.

Something like this, which of course is not working:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE substring(ROUND(latitude, 1), 1, 3) = myinput
                                   /\  /\
              the problem with this values are that the length is variable (20.123, 114, 8965, -0.39, etc.)
```

What I do here is:

- Take the latitude of A: `20.123`
- Round it: To the upper value: `20.123`
- Trim it to the first decimal: `20.1`
- Compare it with the input: `20.1 = 20.1`. OK!

Any ideas how can I archieve my goal? Maybe not use `SUBSTRING` and use regex in order to get *the-number-after-the-dot*? I dont care if I have to use any other functions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its not clear, why you want to use `substring`

Comment: I dont wan't to use `substring`, I'm trying to use substring to do archive that. I dont care if I have to use any other strategy.

Comment: "Round it to the upper value"? What is this supposed to mean?

Comment: `20.78` should round to `20.8` and not to `20.7`.

Comment: But 20.123 shall obviously round to 20.1, not to 20.2. So you don't want to "round to the upper value", you want to round to one decimal place (up or down depending).

Comment: I havent said that `20.123` should round to `20.2`. Look at the second point of the post. It maintains `20.123`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just compare your input having one decimal place of precision against the latitude column rounded to one decimal place:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE ROUND(latitude, 1) = myinput
```

Answer (score 0):

If input decimal precision is not fixed, maybe `like` can do that:

```
select *
from youtable
where latitude like concat(myinput, '%')
```

Here is the [**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f2aa35/1) in SQLFiddle.